# Materialize-CSS Unable to invoke Toast with Angular 2

Tags: angular, materialize, toast

I'm using materialize-css without installing any other npm packages (as suggested on the materialize-css website). The site suggest invoking a javascript method: Materialize.toast('my toast', 2000) in order to programmatically perform a toast. How do I invoke a javascript method against the Materialize object? Does someone have an example?  I'm also using angular/CLI and have jquery and materialize loaded via angular-cli.json

Answer (score 0):

you can use event emitter from **@angular/core**

```
import {MaterializeAction} from 'angular2-materialize';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

export class..     
{ 

`toastModule = new EventEmitter<string|MaterializeAction>();`
..........
now create a function     
`toastMe(){
   this.toastModule.emit('toast');
  }
}`
```

in html

`<a class="btn" (click)="toastMe()" materialize [materializeParams]="['it a toast',4000]" [materializeActions]="toastModule">Toast me </a>`